# How can I dynamically select audio devices?

Tags: windows, audio

A friend of mine and I got into a conversation and realized Windows 7 is missing a key component to its per-application audio settings. You can set volume but you can't stipulate which device each application should use.

Some applications such as ventrilo or skype allow you to select which device to use however, MOST applications simply rely on the current 'Default Audio Device.'

Is there a way to access this? What language would be best used to expose these kinds of functions? Thanks!

Comment: Access what, and from where, exactly?

Comment: @CatPlusPlus - I think the OP wants a way to programmatically rout sound from an arbitrary application to an arbitrary output device. Lots of userland solutions exist for this in OSX, but I'm not aware of a solution for Windows.

Comment: Yes Obsure- I'm looking to assign an application to an audio device of my choosing, assuming there is more than one audio device attached to the machine.

Comment: You can use an AutoHotKey script to quickly switch between two audio devices (Google it and you'll find many scripts doing exactly that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ventrilo and Skype are able to choose which audio device to use because they are coded to directly specify audio output devices instead of just getting the default from the OS. For applications which are coded to use the default Windows device, you can of course change which device is the default device using the sound settings, but this will change the default for the whole system.

Setting different audio devices for separate applications which all use the default audio device isn't something that is necessarily supported by Windows, and many applications use the DirectSound API which complicates the situation further. However, some applications check which device is the default when they initialize and then output exclusively to that device. In this case, you could change the default sound device to one audio device, start a program, then change the default to another audio device, and the first program would continue to use the device which was default when it started up.

However, this is a pretty weak workaround and will only work for specific applications which have been coded in the way described above.

Comment: This is precisely the use-case I want to avoid, launch, set default, launch set default to something else.

Comment: I don't know of a way to set the default windows audio device to appear differently to different running applications. I wouldn't be surprised if it was impossible to do so.